# Process a line in bash as is appears

Tags: performance, bash, shell, unix, pipe

Let's say I have 2 bash commands:

```
$ A
apple
pear
lemon
```

A is writing this really fast but waiting 1 minute after "lemon" to terminate successfully.

I want every line being processed as input for B separately and instantly.
but *I do not want to wait for A to terminate* but rather call a new B for every fast appearing line. B would then add something to the output of A let's say:

```
$ A <for every line appearing> B
1 apple
1 pear
1 banana
```

How can I do this with bash?

**update**

here are the original commands:

```
$sudo alive6 -l eth1 -W 0.2 | sed -e 's/Alive: \(.*\) \[ICMP echo-reply\]/\1%eth0/' -e'/Scanned.*/d' -e'//d'
```

responds instantly, while

```
$sudo alive6 -l eth1 -W 0.2 | sed -e 's/Alive: \(.*\) \[ICMP echo-reply\]/\1%eth0/' -e'/Scanned.*/d' -e'//d' | while read l; do echo $l; done
```

seems to wait for alive6 to finish

Comment: This is a useful thing to keep track of, I'm adding it to my favourites. By the way, I'm guessing you have no way to modify the behaviour of `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A | while read -r l; do B &; done
```

`B` is run in the background to address the following requirement: *line being processed as input for B separately and* ***instantly***.

Comment: If `B` reads standard input you'll need to [use a different file descriptor](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh#L74-L90).

Comment: Why are you backgrounding `B`?

Comment: @l0b0 backgrounding is how I would address the "line being processed as input for B separately and instantly" requirement.

Comment: "Instantly" is not the same as "asynchrously". This solution will end up shuffling lines with `B`'s execution time.

Comment: interestingly this does not make it faster. I actually
have sed as the B-command. A simple example like ls -l && sleep 3 | sed 's/.*/&/' | while read l; do echo $l; done does work though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unbuffer` to disable `A`'s line buffering.

```
$ unbuffer A <for every line appearing> B
```

Comment: @icedwater: And bash scripts would only work if bash is installed.

Comment: Yes, but it is more likely you will find `bash` on a system than `unbuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash:

```
while read -r -u 9 line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
    B "$line"
done 9< <(A)
```

- Works even if `A` prints backslashes.
- Works even if the output of `A` does *not* end in a newline.
- Works even if `B` reads standard input, but not if it for some reason reads file descriptor 9. In that case you'll have to create a pipe with `mkfifo`.
- Runs `B` synchronously, processing the output of `A` asynchrously.